# navigation through view controllers while skipping one - iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller as my initial view controller. 
there's a button in it(GO button) which when the user taps, it should go to another view controller(let's call it Destination view controller with label 'This is where i wanna go'). Meanwhile i want to pass it through a Tabbar controller. The reason is i want to have tabbar in my navigation stack and when users presses back on Destination view controller, it must go to tabbar controller. Picture shows what i want. what can I do to skip tabbar while having it in navigation stack?

[image]

Comment: You can create an array of view controllers and set it to `navigationController.viewControllers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that easily inside the `IBAction` of GO button:

```
@IBAction func goTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myTabBarViewController")
    let vc2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myGoalViewController")
    let controllers = [vc1, vc2]
    self.navigationController!.setViewControllers(self.navigationController!.viewControllers + controllers, animated: true)
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Going to DestinationViewController could be manually:

```
if let destinationViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Storyboard ID of DestinationViewController") {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true)
}
```

(Alternatively, you could make a segue from FirstViewController to the DestinationViewController directly in Storyboard)

And in your DestinationViewController, insert the TabbarController to the Navigation sequence manually after view did appear, then you are able to go back to the TabbarController:

```
class DestinationViewController: UIViewController {
    //......
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if self.isBeingPresented || self.isMovingToParentViewController {
            var viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers

            if let index = viewControllers?.endIndex.advanced(by: -1),
                let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Storyboard ID of TabBarController") {
                viewControllers?.insert(tabBarController, at: index)
                self.navigationController?.viewControllers = viewControllers!
            }
        }
    }
    //......
}
```